# Call to function "file" failed: no file exists - Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file

I have a `template_file` section in my terraform code, which has a variable value to be picked from a file like below

```
data "template_file" "post_sql"{
    template = "${file("/home/user/setup_template.yaml")}"
    vars = {
      name1= data.azurerm_storage_account.newazure_storage_data.name           
      name2="${file("/home/user/${var.newname}loca.txt")}"
    }    
}
```

This file will get generated in the middle of tasks, but terraform looks for it at the starting of `apply` stage itself. I have even tried adding `depends_on` to no avail and throws the below error

```
Call to function "file" failed: no file exists at
/home/user/newnamerloca.txt.
```

How can i make this work, any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try "cat /home/user/newnamerloca.txt" and see if this file is actually in there.

Edit: Currently there is no workaround this, "data" resources are applied at the start of plan/apply thus need to be present in order to use them

Data resources have the same dependency resolution behavior as defined for managed resources. Setting the depends_on meta-argument within data blocks defers reading of the data source until after all changes to the dependencies have been applied.

NOTE: In Terraform 0.12 and earlier, due to the data resource behavior of deferring the read until the apply phase when depending on values that are not yet known, using depends_on with data resources will force the read to always be deferred to the apply phase, and therefore a configuration that uses depends_on with a data resource can never converge. Due to this behavior, we do not recommend using depends_on with data resources.

So maybe something like:

```
data "template_file" "post_sql"{
    template = "${file("/home/user/setup_template.yaml")}"
    vars = {
      name1= data.azurerm_storage_account.newazure_storage_data.name           
      name2="${file("/home/user/${var.newname}loca.txt")}"
    }    
    depends_on = [null_resource.example1]
}

resource "null_resource" "example1" { # **create the file here**
  provisioner "local-exec" {
  command = "open WFH, '>completed.txt' and print WFH scalarlocaltime"
  interpreter = ["perl", "-e"]
  }
}
```

Comment: No, it wont be there, as i mentioned, it gets created at the middle of all tasks, but terraform searches for it in the starting stage itself.

Comment: Currently there is no workaround this, "data" resources are applied at the start of plan/apply thus need to be present in order to use them.

Comment: you can try and create a dependency inside this data resource, see edited post

Comment: As i have mentioned in my post, i have already done that to no avail. :(

Comment: How do you create the file?

Comment: Through powershell

Comment: The only option I see here it either to apply the terraform after the ps script has been completed or use local provisioner to create the file and try to put a dependency on the data source for the provisioner resource. (see edited post)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the behavior you are seeing is included in [the documentation for the `file` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/file.html):

> This function can be used only with files that already exist on disk at the beginning of a Terraform run. Functions do not participate in the dependency graph, so this function cannot be used with files that are generated dynamically during a Terraform operation. We do not recommend using dynamic local files in Terraform configurations, but in rare situations where this is necessary you can use [the `local_file` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/data-sources/file) to read files while respecting resource dependencies.

The `file` function is intended for reading files that are included on disk as part of the configuration, typically in the same directory as the `.tf` file that refers to them, and using the `path.module` symbol to specify the path like this:

```
file("${path.module}/example.tmpl")
```

Your question doesn't explain why you are reading files from a user's home directory rather than from the current module configuration directory, or why one of the files doesn't exist before you run Terraform, so it's hard to give a specific suggestion on how to proceed. The documentation offers [the `local_file` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/data-sources/file) as a possible alternative, but it may not be the best approach depending on your goals. In particular, reading files on local disk from outside of the current module is often indicative of using Terraform for something outside of its intended scope, and so it may be most appropriate to use a different tool altogether.